# Update data in sql table from form - data must be unique

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I've so far learnt only the basics of php and sql and need some directions here.
I have the following code to update data in a row in a sql table - which works fine:

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";//host name
$dbname = "dpuqsevb_tnysx";//database name
$username = "dpuqsevb_user";//username you use to login to php my admin
$password = "password";//password you use to login

//CONNECTION OBJECT
//This Keeps the Connection to the Databade
$conn = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Can not connect to database')      
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked

$url_code = $_POST['url_code'];

$update = "UPDATE url_urls SET url_code='$url_code' WHERE id = 7";

$conn->query($update) or die("Cannot update");//update or error

}

?>

<?php

//Create a query

$sql = "SELECT * FROM url_urls WHERE id = 7";

//submit the query and capture the result

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$query=getenv(QUERY_STRING);

parse_str($query);

?>

<form action="" method="post">

<?php

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="10">

<tr>

<td><input type="text" name="url_code" value="<?php echo $row['url_code']; ?>"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"></td>

</tr>

</table>

<?php   }
?>

</form>

<?php
if($update){//if the update worked

echo "<b>Update successful!</b>";

}  
?>
```

However I want the script to check other rows so there is no duplicate of $url_code - in other words $url_code must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to define the column `url_code` as [`UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) in your database.

Now your query will fail once you try to insert a value where `url_code` already exists in the db. This could also be done via PHP but I really suggest the SQL solution - your database is optimized for exactly this kind of work.